# Как достать значения из массива в JSON файле?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift, iphone

Получаю JSON следующего формата:

```
{ 
  "http://.randomSiteName.com" : 
    [
      "key1 = value1;", "key2 = value2;"
    ] 
}
```

Как вытащить значения (value1...2), ключи (key1...2) и сам сайт из объекта? Пробовал через SwiftyJSON, но там либо nil ловлю, либо пустые значения, которые возвращает библиотека, в случае неудачного парсинга.

Корректный ли формат JSON представления, может из за этого не получается распарсить через SwifyJSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Формат выглядит странно, но синтаксически верен. Пример как можно работать с таким json. Первые строки измените под себя, на них я формирую Ваш json объект.

```
NSString* str = @"{\"http://.randomSiteName.com\" :[\"key1 = value1;\", \"key2 = value2;\"]}";
NSData *raw = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *json = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
NSError *error;
json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:raw options:kNilOptions error:&error];

[json enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString* url, NSArray *values, BOOL *stop) {
    // url = http://.randomSiteName.com
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
    for (NSString *kv in values) {
        // kv = "key1 = value1;" , "key2 = value2;" & etc;
        NSLog(@"%@",kv);
    }

}];
```

Comment: А на свифте такое проделать реально?

Comment: Да, конечно. Синтаксис схож: json.enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock { (url, values, stop) -> Void in

Comment: В этом блоке values я получаю как AnyObject, который не соответсвует протоколу sequenceType, и его не получается перебирать, вот как тут быть я не совсем понял, но нашел решение, которое, почти идентично, но полностью решает мою задачу

Answer (score 0):

```
func JSONParseDictionary(string: String) -> [String: AnyObject]{
  if let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding){
    do {
      if let dictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? [String: AnyObject]{
        return dictionary
      }
    } catch {
      print("error")
    }
  }
  return [String: AnyObject]()
}

let dict = self.JSONParseDictionary(json)

for i in dict.keys {
  print(i) // http://.randomSiteName.com
}

let array = (dict["http://.randomSiteName.com"]?[0] as? String)?.componentsSeparatedByString("=")

for i in array! 
  print(i) // [0]key1, [1]value1
}
```